# How To Create SMS Inbox and Write Information Into SMS Header

Tags: android, sms, aes

I am developing an SMS app with aes256 (message encryption with aes)
 Now I have to solve two problems.

**Question 1:** Is there any source that I can learn how to create a SMS box which has inbox and outbox or something like Android SMS application?

*Other issue:* When I send message, on other side my app will view this message. I want to implement my app information into message header information and when the message arrives from my app, my app will open and view message with inbox and default Android SMS application wouldn't open the coming SMS.

**Question 2:** How can I implement information into message header that will identify my application?

Answer (score 0):

The stock Android SMS/MMS app is part of the Android Open Source Project and full source is available here: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Mms/

The standards used for SMS headers are outlined and referenced here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Data_Header